# Function name out of scope in SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to create an abstraction layer to mimic DB2 functions in Oracle 11g. The goal is to have the customer who is current running DB2 queries repoint to an Oracle abstraction layer without having to change their syntax.

I created the following function under the ABC schema:

```
create or replace function ABC.timestamp(p_date in date) return date is
begin
  return p_date;
end;
```

When I try to use it in a SQL statement, I get an error:

```
select timestamp(current_date) from dual;

ORS-06553: PLS-222: no function with name 'TIMESTAMP' exists in this scope
```

If I call out the schema explicitly it works:

```
select ABC.timestamp(current_date) from dual;
```

I also have a logon trigger that explicitly sets the session's current_schema to ABC.  The only complication I can see is that TIMESTAMP is a keyword in Oracle, but it allows me to create this function with that name.

Any way to get this to work?

Comment: TIMESTAMP is a reserved word.  Also, is your select running from the ABC schema?  If not, then you need to include grants.

Comment: Yes, it's running from ABC.  It seems weird that it doesn't complain during compilation about the reserved word.

Comment: Note, unlike in DB2 the Oracle `DATE` data type has always a time component. So, your function might be useless anyway. I assume function should be `return TRUNC(p_date);` - however why do you write a dedicated function for such basic operation?

Comment: The goal is to have the customer who is current running DB2 queries repoint to an Oracle abstraction layer without having to change their syntax.

Comment: That goal is unattainable. There's all sorts of minor differences in the two database flavours. And even if there weren't you would probably want to rewrite some SQL to take advantage of Oracle's proprietary optimization strategies.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can workaround it "as is". But, if you use double quotes around function name (which is yet another *stupid* thing some people do - and, look at me, I'll do it now), it'll work without owner's name:

```
SQL> create or replace function "timestamp" (p_date in date) return date is
  2  begin
  3    return p_date;
  4  end;
  5  /

Function created.

SQL> select "timestamp"(current_Date) from dual;

"TIMESTA
--------
11.01.18

SQL>
```

However, it means that you'll ALWAYS have to use double quotes when referencing that function.

If I were you, I'd change function name. As you can see, the fact that you *can* do something doesn't mean that you *should* do it.

Comment: Are you using SQL*Plus to execute that here? I'm a little surprised that the results have the column name `"TIMESTA`. I seem to remember it following capitalisation (no access to a DB atm). And I couldn't agree more with the last paragraph!

Comment: Yes, @Ben, it was copy/paste from my SQLPlus session. When there's no alias, it returns first "n" characters of the column name returned by a query. In this case, those were double quotes followed by TIMESTA as NLS settings say that the result is DD.MM.YY. When I modified it to DD.MM.YYYY, the result's "column name" was "TIMESTAMP (without the closing double quotes).

Comment: I can reproduce your result, but unfortunately for my requirement I can't change that name since the incoming queries are written for DB2 and expect `timestamp` to be a valid function.

Comment: OK; so, what will you do?

Comment: Are you're using SQL PL or PL/SQL in DB2 @Paul? If you using SQL PL then your trigger code is very slightly different anyway so you might just as well change the name of the function in this instance (or if this is what your function is actually doing remove it entirely and use `cast()` instead if it's really needed). If you're using PL/SQL then doesn't DB2 implement whatever the Oracle syntax is enabling you to reverse which one you're mimicing?

Comment: Looks like I'll have to go back to the customer to see if they can change their SQL.  Was hoping to provide a seamless move to Oracle.